# WPF MVVM DataBinding issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

Can some one explain why the ViewModel that is assigned in CodeBehind is not being utilized in the WPF Extended Control 'BusyIndicator' implemented with the following code:

ViewModel implementation:

```cs
public partial class App : Application {

        private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs seArgs) {
            MainWindowView mwv = new MainWindowView();
            mwv.DataContext = new DataSetViewModel(new DataSetModel());
            mwv.Show();

        }

    }
```

XAML:

```xml
<kit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" DisplayAfter="0" >

            <kit:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="4">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=WaitProgressUploadTitle}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=WaitProgressUploadContent}" />
                                <ProgressBar Value="40" Height="15"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 2 0"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2 0 0 0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </kit:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
                <kit:BusyIndicator.OverlayStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#ffffeeee"/>
                    </Style>
                </kit:BusyIndicator.OverlayStyle>
                <kit:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Style>
                </kit:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>

                <StackPanel>
                    <kitdg:DataGridControl Name="DataPreview" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dvLbSelection}" Visibility="{Binding Path=FileOpenBad,Converter={StaticResource errorVisibility}}" ReadOnly="True"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileOpenText}" Margin="0,100,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="675" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Visibility="{Binding Path=FileOpenGood,Converter={StaticResource errorVisibility}}" />
                </StackPanel>

            </kit:BusyIndicator>
```

The following is displayed in the output window for VS2010:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'WaitProgressUploadTitle' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-1880398257)'. BindingExpression:Path=WaitProgressUploadTitle; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-1880398257); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'WaitProgressUploadContent' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-1880398257)'. BindingExpression:Path=WaitProgressUploadContent; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-1880398257); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'connectionStringValidity' property not found on 'object' ''DataSetViewModel' (HashCode=3476046)'. BindingExpression:Path=connectionStringValidity; DataItem='DataSetViewModel' (HashCode=3476046); target element is 'Image' (Name='errorInvalidSQLConnection'); target property is 'ToolTip' (type 'Object')

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the `DataContext` on your `BusyIndicator` control. You're setting it on the `MainWindowView` object. What you can do is to name your `MainWindowView` internally and set the `DataContext` of your `BusyIndicator` control like so (obviously replacing `NameOfMainWindowView` with whatever name you give to you window internally):

```
<kit:BusyIndicator DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=NameOfMainWindowView}"
IsBusy="True" DisplayAfter="0" >
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `Binding`.